# misterious collapse of Fedora 18 on a dual system

Tags: windows-7, linux, fedora, multi-boot, shutdown

I've recently (about a month ago) installed Windows 7 and Fedora 18 as a dual system on my Dell Vostro laptop, and everything went well until my Fedora started shutting down out of a sudden, just like that. When this reached the end of my patience, I tried to reinstall Fedora 18 on that specific partition (size: 77 GB), but while installing Fedora 18, it still shuts down, so I can't get over with the installation, moreover, I can't reach my Windows-partitions, because of the missing grub bootloader. What could I do?

NOTE: When I was on Windows, it didn't suddenly shut down.
UPDATE: It seems that the shutdown persists regardless the Linux distribution. I tried to install Ubuntu 11.10. I can't get through the installation process. I'm clueless.

Comment: Is it by any chance overheating and shutting down because of that?

Can you describe what happens in more detail? Do you even get an error message? Does it just shutdown all power? Does it immediately reboot?

Comment: Overheating? My laptop does sometimes overheat, but it never ever shut down this way. I don't get any error message end it doesn't reboot. The screen turns black and that's all.

Comment: @Eszter, CPU overheating does shut the machine down. Trying to restart immediately won't work, need to let it cool down. Linux tends to be much more demanding than Windows, so overheating is a definite possibility. Another one might be graphics driver flakiness, try installing in text-only mode.